# Sequelize findOne latest entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to find the latest entry in a table. What is the best way to do this? The table has Sequelize's default `createdAt` field.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Method `findOne` is wrapper for `findAll` method. Therefore you can simply use `findAll` with limit 1 and order by id descending.

Example:

```
YourModel.findAll({
  limit: 1,
  where: {
    //your where conditions, or without them if you need ANY entry
  },
  order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ]]
}).then(function(entries){
  //only difference is that you get users list limited to 1
  //entries[0]
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `createdAt`, not `id` on line 6. Submitted an edit: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2345804

Comment: Usually id is auto increment. Therefore the highest value of id means the last added entry. But yes you could use `createdAt`.

Comment: If you are sure that you prefer createdAt, I will accept your edit.

Comment: And what? `findOne` returns an object and `findAll` returns an array! It is a huge difference!

Comment: Yes that is true. And I think that I pointed it in code sample.
I wrote there :
" //only difference is that you get users list limited to 1".
In my opinion it is clear info that you get list/array.
But if you still think that this should be stronger pointed I will do it.

Comment: @Noah this could be obvious but just to clarify the thing about using createdAt vs id, they aren't the same, normally your id field will be indexed since it is the primary key, createdAt is not indexed in most of cases, this has impact on the query time due to you're using "order by"

Comment: Basically, since `id` is auto increment, both fields, `id` and `createdAt` can do the job, if you have to choose, probably the `id` will do it faster

Comment: @Polak Strictly speaking, I'd prefer `createdAt` unless you (a) can prove it's faster (which, since datetimes are integers under the hood, isn't guaranteed!) and (b) have a need, because sorting by `createdAt` is much clearer than by ID -- if you're sorting by the date something was `createdAt`, you're obviously looking for chronological order. In contrast, `id` is a bit less clear.

Comment: @NicHartley, yeah, I agree with you if assuming id and createdAt were both already indexed, of course createdAt is clearer but as I told before, createdAt is normally an audit field not indexed and there's a trade off choosing between being clearer by adding a new index in your database vs reusing the primary key, maintaining only one index which won't slow down inserts/deletes performance and also saves disk space, to sumarize, just wanted to explain that depending on the situation, one option might be better than the other

Answer (score 174):

```
model.findOne({
    where: { key },
    order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ]],
});
```

Comment: Hi szym; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: No. Simple question. Simple answer. You don't need more than that. I was looking for the answer myself and this much information is exactly what I was looking for myself. In chaos of too much information often less is more.

Comment: @syzm why would someone order results when there is only one result being returned by your method
and what if you don't have the key ? In most cases we don't have access to keys of latest entries.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq because ordering it by the createdAt is what is determining the latest entry.

Comment: I also think this is a better answer than the original post as it utilizes the correct Sequelize method, requires less parameters, and doesn't need to be unwrapped from an array. I also think @VinceBowdren 's request for more context is invalid as there is no context in the original question warranting any explanation.

Comment: to find the latest entry without knowing the key, just omit the `where` parameter entirely

Comment: @szym do I need to set key or is this useable as is? Kinda guessing key is suppose to be a  field that exists on the model?

Answer (score 13):

If someone has turned timestamps false, you can do it with id too. This one worked for me.

```
model.findOne({
order: [ [ 'id', 'DESC' ]],
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Everyone using `createdAt` risk the chance of getting the wrong object because ISO8601 dates in sequelize is second precise.  If you have 2 objects created the same second, it's possible it will find and return the wrong one.  If you're using an incremental ID, it's guaranteed to be in order.

Comment: unless you are using UUID :)

Comment: You are assuming that `id` is a sequential number here which isn't necessary in every case. It wouldn't work when it's a non-number or not sequential.