# Sequelize get last update or create value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause

I need to find the latest create or update entry in a table and return.

Example

```
const data = MyModel.findOne({
   where: { id },
   ordered: [[ //createdAt and updatedAt]]   

})
console.log(data.exampleLastUpdateOrCreateValue)
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequelize findOne latest entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445849/sequelize-findone-latest-entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try doing this way

```js
const data = MyModel.findOne({
   where: { id },
   order: [['updatedAt', 'DESC' ]]   

})
console.log(data.exampleLastUpdateOrCreateValue)
```

You can also make use of `id` if it auto-incremented